# pre-push no such file, when file is available

Tags: git, rspec, githooks

> fatal: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-push: No such file or directory

### pre-push file in .git/hooks/pre-push

```
#!/bin/env bash
echo "Running RSpec"
bundle exec rspec spec
spec=$?

if [ $spec -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -en "\\033[32mTests are green, pushing...\\033[0;39m\n"
  exit 0
else
  echo -en "\\033[1;31mCannot push, tests are failing. Use --no-verify to force push.\\033[0;39m\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

I ran..

```
chmod u+x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

and got the code from here:

https://gist.github.com/johnhamelink/577b8613ae82d2b3037b

Comment: `#!/bin/env` is probably wrong. It only works if `env` lives in `/bin`; typically `env` is in `/usr/bin`. If `/usr/bin` is just an alias for `/bin`, it will work, but you are probably not using such a system.

Comment: @torek, I'm on a Mac and its deployed to heroic and circle ci, linux, should I just change #!/bin/env bash to #!/usr/bin/env bash
? As I get the same error, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *it's deployed to ...* as your scripts run on whichever system is hosting Git—in this case, your laptop. But yes, on the Mac `env` is in /usr/bin; bash itself is in /bin but `#!/usr/bin/env bash` should work there. You can test the script itself by running `.git/hooks/pre-push` manually too, to see if there are other typos.

Comment: All hooks are executable tools. Run it directly with `$ .git/hooks/pre-push` and see what happens. Let's try to divide things into small pieces.